# Exclude RichFaces JS files in CombinedResourceHandler

Tags: jsf, richfaces, omnifaces, combinedresourcehandler

Is it possible for the [`CombinedResourceHandler`](http://showcase.omnifaces.org/resourcehandlers/CombinedResourceHandler) to ignore RichFaces JS files?

When I let omnifaces combine all JS files, including RichFaces with Richfaces optimisation off

```
<context-param>
   <param-name>org.richfaces.resourceOptimization.enabled</param-name>
   <param-value>false</param-value>
</context-param>
```

I get the following exception

```
SEVERE: Error Rendering View[/login.xhtml]
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.richfaces.resource.ExternalStaticResource.getURL(ExternalStaticResource.java:90)
    at org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CombinedResourceInfo.loadResources(CombinedResourceInfo.java:229)
    at org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CombinedResourceInfo.getLastModified(CombinedResourceInfo.java:303)
    at org.omnifaces.resourcehandler.CombinedResource.getRequestPath(CombinedResource.java:92)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.StylesheetRenderer.encodeEnd(StylesheetRenderer.java:106)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HeadRenderer.encodeHeadResources(HeadRenderer.java:105)
    at com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.HeadRenderer.encodeEnd(HeadRenderer.java:92)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponentBase.encodeEnd(UIComponentBase.java:875)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1786)
    at javax.faces.component.UIComponent.encodeAll(UIComponent.java:1782)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.renderView(FaceletViewHandlingStrategy.java:424)
    at com.sun.faces.application.view.MultiViewHandler.renderView(MultiViewHandler.java:125)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.caucho.server.webbeans.ConversationJsfViewHandler.renderView(ConversationJsfViewHandler.java:81)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrapper.renderView(ViewHandlerWrapper.java:288)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.RenderResponsePhase.execute(RenderResponsePhase.java:121)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:101)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at org.apache.myfaces.extensions.cdi.jsf2.impl.listener.phase.CodiLifecycleWrapper.render(CodiLifecycleWrapper.java:126)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    ...
```

However, regardless of what I enter in the context param `org.omnifaces.COMBINED_RESOURCE_HANDLER_EXCLUDED_RESOURCES`, I am unable to exclude any of the Richfaces resources. I tried param values such as

```
<param-value>richfaces:richfaces.js, richfaces:richfaces-queue.js, richfaces:richfaces-base-component.js</param-value>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to supply the exact resource identifiers. Those aren't valid RichFaces resource identifiers. You seem to have guessed them. You can easily determine them by looking at the generated HTML output when **not** using `CombinedResourceHandler`. Given a context path of `/playground` and JSF mapping of `*.xhtml`, it'll look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/playground/javax.faces.resource/richfaces.js.xhtml"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/playground/javax.faces.resource/richfaces-base-component.js.xhtml"></script>
```

The part after the `/javax.faces.resource/` *without* JSF mapping is the resource name. The part in the `ln` request parameter is the resource library (however, as you probably observed, RichFaces has none!). The resource identifier is represented by `library:name` notation, or just `name` if there's no library.

So, this should do it for you:

```
<context-param>
    <param-name>org.omnifaces.COMBINED_RESOURCE_HANDLER_EXCLUDED_RESOURCES</param-name>
    <param-value>richfaces.js, richfaces-queue.js, richfaces-base-component.js</param-value>
</context-param>
```

Note that disobeying the resource library (and homebrewing another layer over it) is indeed a severe mistake of RichFaces. See also among others [What is the JSF resource library for and how should it be used?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11988415/what-is-the-jsf-resource-library-for-and-how-should-it-be-used/)

---

**Unrelated** to the concrete question, I can't reproduce issue 39 anymore using RichFaces 4.3.6. Feel free to reopen the issue at [GitHub](https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues), along with the minimum information necessary to reproduce the problem ourselves starting with a completely blank project.

Comment: thanks for your quick reply. I must confess I did attempt to guess the param values as nothing seemed to work, but even values without a resource identifier such as just "richfaces.js" has no effect. They always seem to be combined.

Comment: p.s I defined the context params in web.xml

Comment: Works for me. Have you read and understood the first part of the answer which explains how to determine them? Have you applied this information in your particular case? In any way, you'd better tell minimum information necessary to reproduce the problem ourselves starting with a completely blank project (for example, RichFaces version, etc).

Comment: You were right thank you - it seemed to be a custom function that was swallowing up most of richfaces.js file.

Comment: @BalusC Is it possible to exclude a whole library with a wildcard with `library:*.js` or something similar?

Comment: @MathieuCastets: Nope, unfortunately not. Idea isn't bad tho.